# Constantly Populate/Update SQL Server table from XML file or webservice? Keeping minimal support in mind

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

In a SQL Server database I have a Products table that holds ProductID, ProductName, Price and other data associated to the ProductID. I would like to get this data updated daily for Price Changes and also for any new products not in the SQL table.

Would it be easiest to get the Product data from an XML file and import this data into the SQL Products table OR consume a web service with the data? Just looking for everyones thoughts on the quickest and easiest way with minimal support going forward. Thanks in advance, I appreciate..

Answer (score 1):

If your "Product" object is fairly straightforward and well defined, I would do this:

- define an XML schema (XSD) for your XML file
- create a small console app that will

  - be called by a scheduler (e.g. Windows "Scheduled Tasks") regularly (every 2 minutes, every 8 hours - totally up to you)
  - opens an XML file in a fixed location (if it's there) - or calls a web service to get the XML as an alternative
  - deserializes that XML into a list of "Product" objects
  - updates the database according to the data in the "Product" objects

You could easily have e.g. a flag `IsNew` to flag the new products, and for existing products, your XML might only contain the `ProductID` and the new `Price`.

Based on those things, it should be pretty simple to write a small app to parse the XML you get (from web service or XML file), and then loop through those `Product` entries that have changed and update those (or insert them, if they're new).

Answer (score 0):

Depends:

1. If the XML file must be imported to SQL Products table manually on each new updates, then a web service will be the cleanest, fastest and easiest option.
2. If the XML file will be placed in a system defined folder, a Windows service or Linux daemon could be built to watch permanently (on real time) that path to transfer the updated data.
3. if doesn't exists yet a defined structure for XML file, the web service can "talk" directly with database and omit the XML and WinService/LinuxDaemon building.

**-DT**